# Magento websites will not load in safari and chrome

Tags: magento, google-chrome, browser, safari

We have two website both built on magento the addresses are:
 - www.lightsave.co.uk
 - www.theledspecialist.co.uk

Neither of the sites will load in safari or firefox and there must be an issue with the code or script but I am not experienced enough to identify it.

I greatly appreciate and help anyone can offer me.

Kind regards,
Oliver

Comment: Hello, www.lightsave.co.uk is loading, slow but it's loading, but with www.theledspecialist.co.uk there's definitely something wrong as Safari "eat" 5.4GB of RAM and 100% CPU during load. Please attache php, apache (unless you're using other server), system.log and exception.log.